# Always open a Pdf on a given page when button pressed

Tags: jquery, pdf

The following test code was made for the purposes of asking my question.
Running it for the first time and clicking the button, opens the Pdf on the first page.
This is correct and works for all the latest browsers.

If I then scroll the Pdf to another page and re-click the button, the Pdf only opens on the first page again with Google Chrome. Nothing happens in the other browsers and the page remains the same.

My question is, does anyone know how to get the Pdf to return to the first page using FF and IE.

I am more than happy to completely change my approach if anyone has any ideas.

Many thanks.

```
<input type="button" id="getP1" value="Get Page 1" />

<div class="pdf"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#getP1").click(function () {
      var fname = "/PDFFiles/Somefile.pdf#page=1";
      $('div.pdf').replaceWith("<div class='pdf'><iframe src='" + fname + "' height='500px'></iframe></div>");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a query string parameter after the file name. It should make the browser think that it's a new document and load it again.

```
<input type="button" id="getP1" value="Get Page 1" />

<div class="pdf"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#getP1").click(function () {
      var ticks = new Date().getTime();
      var fname = "/PDFFiles/Somefile.pdf#page=1";
      $('div.pdf').replaceWith("<div class='pdf'><iframe src='" + fname + "?" + ticks + "' height='500px'></iframe></div>");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello jgauffin, Many thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it did not change things at all. Out of curiosity, did you try it yourself by any chance? I am wondering if the problem only happens on my machine. However, I am not convinced.

Comment: No, I did not try it. It was a theory. Did you remove the `#page=1` before trying?

Comment: I am afraid that is one of the problems with writing simple test code as an example of the problem. Without going into details, removing the #page=1 would completely defeat tho object as, in reality, the page would be changed according to circumstances. Pehaps I should have written #page=36 in my example. Thanks for your help anyway jgauffin. I hope the fact that someone has replied to my question does not put off anyone who might have an answer, because this problem is driving me nuts.

Comment: It should be added after the querystring IIRC. Like this: `Somefile.pdf?theTicksCount#page=1` to be a proper link.

Comment: I think I may have messed up the last commet so I will try entering it again.
@jgauffin. I tried many way of implementing your suggestion.
eg. var fname = "/PDFFiles/1895Magpie07.pdf?ts=" + ticks + "#page=1";
but nothing works.
To see what I mean, it would be necessary to actually run the example in FF or IE.
However, I appreciate that would be asking to much so again I thank you for tryingto help.