# Repeatedly open a PDF at a specific page. (even after a scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I asked a similar question to this a week ago but perhaps I did not make the question clear enough.

I have since been struggling to find something that works, but without success.

Using the latest version of all the common browsers I want to display a PDF opened on a specific page.

---

**Using Chrome** - Does what I want :-)

Pressing the button opens the PDF on page 3.
If the user scrolls the pdf to a different page and then re-presses the button the PDF opens again on page 3;

**Using FF,IE or Safari**

Pressing the button opens the PDF on page 3.
If the user scrolls the pdf to a different page and then re-presses the button nothing happens.

---

Does anyone know how I can get the page to always open on page 3 with all the latest browsers?
I am more than happy to completely change my approach, including using a free plugin if necessary.

If anyone knows that what I am trying to do can ONLY be done in Chrome then I would be grateful if they could let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Test for SO</title>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="test" value="Test" type="button" />
    <br />
  <iframe id="iFrame" width="500" height="600"></iframe>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () {
      var fileName = "/PDFFiles/pages.pdf#page=3";
      $('#iFrame').attr("src", fileName);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you can give a reference to your other question. Or you could have editted your other question to make it more clear?

Comment: Are you saying that people would notice that I had edited my question? I did not know that, I will do that in future. Thank you for the information. 
In my past experience, people sometimes respond with a guess or something unhelpful like "Why do you want to do that", and then no one else bothers. Can you help me with my problem?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717993/always-open-a-pdf-on-a-given-page-when-button-pressed/9718095#comment12356428_9718095

Comment: I think only Adobe PDF plugin supports the page parameter. <code>&lt;a href="http://www.example.com/sample_doc.pdf?page=3"&gt;Page 3 in sample_doc.pdf&lt;/a&gt;</code> You can also <a href="http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=217&t=Trouble-free_Linking_To_PDF_Pages_Online">add a PDF action to the document so that it opens a particular page</a>. I have shown how to do this using our product PDFOne .NET but you can add the PDF action using any other tool.

Comment: @PeteDavies please select the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

This works for Chrome

```
<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4">
```

To make this work in all Browsers, `PDF has to be coded to open to a specific page.`
This can be done  using Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Google's document viewer as follows:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:500px;" onload="javascript:this.contentWindow.location.hash='#:0.page.4';" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The essential part is the `onload` function which adds the **zero-based index** page number to show:

```
onload="javascript:this.contentWindow.location.hash='#:0.page.4';"
```

If you need a button to make the iframe reload, just update the iframe src (I think that's the easiest method, but I may be wrong):

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('iframe').attr("src", function() { 
    return this.src;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fudgey. I appreciate your suggestion. It will probably take me a while to set it up so I will do it tomorrow at work. I will obviously report how I get on but I am sure the is bound to be SOMETHING that prevents it from working :-)

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the following but it did not work.
The code should open a pdf if you want to try it.
<iframe onload="javascript:this.contentWindow.location.hash=':0.page.3';" 
src="https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0BWfYHJlhNrTEU3bnB5QnVRZzJIWkJOaDd3VG5udw&embedded=true"
style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></iframe>

Comment: Hmm, actually it works in non-Chrome browsers. It seems Chrome gives an error `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL`...

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to set the iframe src to something else, then back at the correct document. for a short time only.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I just tried your suggestion, but I am afraid it did not work. I believe this problem is not a simple one but there must be an answer out there somewhere.

Comment: Martin: you must destroy and recreate the entire iframe DOM node. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10791643/640113

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy and re-create the iframe node itself.  For example:

```
<input id="test" value="Test" type="button" />

<br />

<div id="wrapper"> 
 <!-- iframe will be continually destroyed and re-created here --> 
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create the initial iframe on page load
    $('<iframe id="iFrame" width="500" height="600" src="/PDFFiles/pages.pdf">').appendTo('#wrapper');

    // Destroy and recreate iframe on button click, starting on your desired page.

    $("#test").click(function () {

     if($('#iFrame').length) { 
       $('#iFrame').remove(); 
     }

     var page = 3;
     $('<iframe id="iFrame" width="500" height="600" src="/PDFFiles/pages.pdf#page='+page+'">').appendTo('#wrapper');

    });

</script>​​​​​​​
```

Note: There will be a moment in which the PDF loads again on the first page, but you may be able to hide it under an ajax loader ball for a 1-2 seconds, then by the time you make it visible it will have jumped to your desired page.